# Realtek drivers on Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, realtek

I have an installation on an HDD, server 18.04 destined to be an in-house intranet site, OTRS.  I have a nice tower to put it on, i5 processor, 8GB RAM, Realtek 8111c LAN device.

I built the system on an ageing laptop, 10 year old but good for its time, core2Duo, 6GB RAM with Broadcom chip that required no effort to install.

I've been trying to get it to work nicely with the Realtek in the tower (MSI H61M-P31 G3).  I do not have any other LAN adapters to hand, and I'm contemplating buying one and disabling the onboard. Last chance to get Realtek working.

Using the laptop with broadcom, I entered `sudo apt install r8168-dkms` which  completes nicely, no errors in output. I shutdown, transplant HDD to tower, boot up, Realtek 8111c not enabled.

Have tried rolling back kernel from 4.15.0-38 to 4.15.0-36
Also tried latest r8168-dkms 8.046.00-1 (in the cosmic repository and debian) instead of the apt provided 8.045.08-2 for bionic.

Pretty much followed these steps [unixblogger.com](https://www.unixblogger.com/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/)

Have not tried the manual way, because r8168-dkms reports install completed successfully, no errors, so I don't think it could work any better manually.  Also, want it to work reliably when the Kernel upgrades, not have to manually install each time.

Is the issue because I'm installing r8168-dkms without the chip present, then transplanting the HDD in to the other PC with the realtek chip?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was misunderstanding the problem and asking the wrong question.  The correct question was, how do I introduce a new NIC on Ubuntu Server 18.04

I bought an Intel card, fitted it and it failed to work until I performed a reinstall, meaning that the NIC does not show under ifconfig if added after install.